# How to use promise and loop over mongoose collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm making chat inside my website. To store data I use Chat, User, Messages collections.

I want results to be in Array containing:

```
[{
  username (another one, not me)
  last update
  last message
}]
```

In Chat model I have only `chatid` and `array of two members`, so I need to loop through User collection to get `user name` using `user id` from it. I want to save in array all names (in future I would also like to loop through messages to get latest messages for each `chatid`). Issue is that when I return chatsList it is empty. I think I need somehow to use `Promise`, but I'm not completely sure how it should work.

```
Chat.find({ members: userId })
    .then(chats => {
      let chatsList = [];
      chats.forEach((chat, i) => {
        let guestId = chat.members[1 - chat.members.indexOf(userId)];
        User.findOne({ _id: guestId })
          .then(guest => {
            let chatObj = {};
            name = guest.name;
            chatsList.push(name);
            console.log("chatsList", chatsList)
          })
          .catch(err => console.log("guest err =>", err))
      })
      return res.json(chatsList)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      errors.books = "There are no chats for this user";
      res.status(400).json(errors);
    })
```

Comment: Where do you return `chatsList` and where is it empty?

Comment: You chats model should have two users sender and receiver and your first query should be Chats.find({sender : {$in : 'array containing your user id and one more user id'}, receiver: {$in : 'array containing your user id and one more user id'}})

Comment: @fjc in line `return res.json(chatsList)`

Comment: @JackOfAshes-MohitGawande I store it in one array - `members`. `members = [id1,id2]`, that's in order to get chat guest I use `guestId`

Comment: @Angelzzz: so what order you will follow in line `let guestId = chat.members[1 - chat.members.indexOf(userId)];` you are assuming some order. Right? how will you ensure who is guest if you are using app next is guest and if someone else is using app you will be guest.

Comment: @VishwaDeepakSingh there is array with two users (index 0 and 1). If I user 0, then guest is user 1 and vice versa :), so guestId is always guest id, not mine

Comment: @Angelzzz: Is guestId a completely different attribute? Asking because I see in code you are driving it like `chat.members[1 - chat.members.indexOf(userId)]` this.

Comment: Please forget about guestid. I'm sure in this line it works ok. Don't understand why.you ask about it. It does nothing in this case. It can be hardcoded to any number in this example

Comment: @Angelzzz: can you please check if solution provided in answers is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is what you are looking for:

```
Chat.find({ members: userId })
    .then(chats => {
        let userPromises = [];
        chats.forEach((chat, i) => {
            let guestId = chat.members[1 - chat.members.indexOf(userId)];
            userPromises.push(User.findOne({ _id: guestId }));
        });
        return Promise.all(userPromises).then(guests => {
            let chatsList = [];
            guests.forEach(guest => {
                chatsList.push(guest.name);
            });
            return res.json(chatsList);
        });
    });
});
```

although it would probably be better to do a single call to DB with a list of ids (`$in` query). Something like this:

```
Chat.find({ members: userId })
    .then(chats => {
        let ids = [];
        chats.forEach((chat, i) => {
            let guestId = chat.members[1 - chat.members.indexOf(userId)];
            ids.push(guestId);
        });
        return User.find({_id: {$in: ids}}).then(guests => {
            let chatsList = [];
            guests.forEach(guest => {
                chatsList.push(guest.name);
            });
            return res.json(chatsList);
        });
    });
});
```

You may want to additionally validate if every `id` had a corresponding `guest`.

Comment: Thank you! Can please tell more about single call to DB? How to make it?

Comment: what if I want to make chatsList an array of objects and add chatId into it also?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Chat.find({ members: userId }).then(chats => {
    let guestHashMap = {};


    chats.forEach(chat => {
        let guestId = chat.members.filter(id => id != userId)[0];
        // depending on if your ID is of type ObjectId('asdada')
        // change it to guestHashMap[guestId.toString()] = true;
        guestHashMap[guestId] = true;
    })
    return Promise.all(
        // it is going to return unique guests
        Object.keys(guestHashMap)
            .map(guestId => {
                // depending on if your ID is of type ObjectId('asdada')
                // change it to User.findOne({ _id: guestHashMap[guestId] })
                return User.findOne({ _id: guestId })
            }))
})
.then(chats => {
    console.log(chats.map(chat => chat.name))
    res.json(chats.map(chat => chat.name))
})
.catch(err => {
    errors.books = "There are no chats for this user";
    res.status(400).json(errors);
})
```

Comment: how can this help? I'm ok with how I get guestId, it works well

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23082604)

Comment: @Towkir - can you please review again. I am sorry I failed to understand question in first attempt.

Comment: @Angelzzz: My Bad.

Comment: @Angelzzz : would you mind upvoting my answer in that case. I lost my reputation because of my irresponsible behaviour here.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into concurrency issues. For example, running `chats.forEach`, and inside `forEach` running `User.findOne().then`: The `return` statement is already executed before the `User.findOne()` promise has resolved. That's why your list is empty.

You could get more readable and working code by using `async/await`:

```
async function getChatList() {
    const chats = await Chat.find({members: userId});
    const chatsList = [];
    for (const chat of chats) {
        let guestId = chat.members[1 - chat.members.indexOf(userId)];
        const guest = await User.findOne({_id: guestId});
        chatsList.push(guest.name);
    }
    return chatsList;
}
```

Then the code to actually send the chat list back to the user:

```
try {
    return res.json(await getChatList());
} catch (err) {
    // handle errors;
}
```